# SQL get count of all rows that have the same id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have a table called story_comment with (integer) columns story_id, and comment_id. I want to know how many comments each story has but I'm not sure the best way to write the sql query.

The query should return a table with the columns story_id and num_comments (where num_comments is the number of rows in story_comment where story_id is the same as the story_id in that results row).

Desired Results (Example):

story_id  |  num_comments

```
   4  |            17
   6  |             0
   7  |             4
```

I was able to do this for one particular story_id with the query:

```
SELECT story_id, Count(story_id) as num_comments FROM story_comment where story_id=20;
```

but I'm not sure how I can do this for every story_id in the table.  Side note I'm going to be doing this query using mysqli in php.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

```
SELECT story_id, Count(story_id) as num_comments FROM story_comment  
GROUP BY story_id
```

> The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate
>   functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: glad to have helped

Answer (score 1):

To make aggregate functions like `count()` apply to each unique value of a column instead to the complete table, add a `group by`

```
SELECT story_id, Count(*) as num_comments 
FROM story_comment
group by story_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, this was exactly what I needed!